# Vaadin adding a image map with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: java, eclipse, google-maps, maps, vaadin

I'm trying to create a vaadin project where the user would enter the latitude and longitude and then maybe press a button so it would find that exact location in google maps. How would I connect that to happen?

Comment: You can just add a marker to show the location https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [leaflet addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/v-leaflet:vaadin) for vaadin. You would then create a LMarker object with the longitude and latiude and add it to the map.